# Display same div multiple times based upon dynamically generated checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am currently tackling some `JQuery` and `Javascript` and I have encountered a small problem that I can't for the life of me figure out how to solve.

I have a `form` which dynamically loads information from a `json` file which re-uses a "wpTemplate" and populates a select list. This `form` compromises something of the following;

```
 <div class="wp" id="wpTemplate" >
    <input type="checkbox" id="wpCheck" name="" class="wp" value="">
    <label id="wpLabel" class="wpLabel"></label>

    <div class="uc" id="uc">
       <select class="ucSelect" id="ucSelect" name="case" multiple>
          <option id="option" class="option"></option>
       </select>
    </div>
 </div>
```

In essence, there could be multiple `div` "wpTemplate". My aim is to somehow have the ability to select either one or many "wpCheck" `checkbox` and for the "uc" `div` to display depending on the specific `checkbox` being selected.

I tried adding `style="display: none;"` to the "uc" `class` and a simple `if-else` statement with the show/hide functionality but to no avail.

```
$('.wp').each(function() {
   if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('.uc').show();
   } else {
      $('.uc').hide();
   }
});
```

I'm new to `JQuery` so any help or alternative ways would be much appreciative.

Comment: can you show some actual code and maybe comments on where you are having issues?

Comment: Better replace id `wpTemplate` with class: id must be unique on the page.

Comment: I made you a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L0bco1h5/4/. I changed your ids to classes because it have to be unique. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$('.wpCheck').on('change', function () {
  var $uc = $(this).closest('.wpTemplate').find('.uc')
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $uc.show()
  } else {
    $uc.hide()
  }
})
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gu8b03cp/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input.wp').change(function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(":checked"))
        {
            $this.siblings('div.uc').show();
        }
        else
        {
            $this.siblings('div.uc').hide();
        }
        });
    });
```

[fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/0p72436n/10/)